How to Convert CSV Data from Teensy 4.1 CAN Bus to MDF4 Format via USB
I'm working on a project where a Teensy 4.1 microcontroller reads data from a car's CAN bus and saves it to a CSV file on an SD card. My goal is to connect the Teensy to a computer via USB and export the data from the SD card in MDF4 file format.
The microcontroller code is written in C, and I want to handle the conversion to MDF4, preferably in C on the computer. I've only found methods to do this in Python, but I'm unsure how to properly transfer the CSV data from the Teensy to the computer and convert it to MDF4.
Does anyone have a detailed approach or example code for implementing this process?

I do not see what you are asking about. You describe what you want to do (use python to convert a file to another format), where you want to do it (on a PC, i.e. not on the microcontroller). Then you note that you found a way to do it in python (i.e. exactly what you want to do). I completely miss the point where you need help with a programming problem. So please apply [ask] to focus on the programming problem you want help with, on how you tried it and how exactly it failed. Otherwise this will continue to give an off-topic impression.

Ok, so you want it preferably in C. Why? Python can do it; why not use it? Also, why discuss the origin of the file? You just want to convert as file.
